# How to perform a login and pass and receive parameters to the next page using JSF and ADF in JDeveloper 11g?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

please, help am new in jsf an adf, I need an guiade that explicate this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read about ADF Security - there is a whole layer that will automate the authentication and authorization for your app.
Here is an overview - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYbFBeZWjUQ